# How to vertically align text in list view on JQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I need to vertically align my text in `<li>` elements

Currently I am setting the `line-height` as below, however this means it doesn't work on all screen sizes.

I have tried applying `vertical-algn:middle` and setting the height to 50% to no avail.

```
<ul id="optionsList" style="line-height:0; height:93vh;" data-role="listview">

  <li class="listItem" id="divTSScroller" style="display: block;overflow: hidden;">
    <div style="float:left;">               
        <span style="line-height:160px; font-size: 4vw;">Timesheet</span>
    </div>
  //another list item
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

use flex to set centered element, such as free text:

```css
li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

If you have few children elements,
set the `flex-direction` to `column` and use `align-items: center` instead:

```css
li {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```